# how to use java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() under mono android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

how to use this java code indo mono android.

```
String[] str ={"su","-c","reboot recovery"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);
```

There is no option for `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` in mono.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

In Mono for Android that's mapped to [Java.Lang.Runtime.Exec](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aJava.Lang.Runtime/M/Exec).

The equivalent code in C# is `Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec()`